# How to measure DPWD on VMware?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, diskmanagement

I want to know the amount of data read and especially written per day, per week, per month.

But how to achieve this on VMware?

The disk which are integrated differ. E.g. the disks are in SANs, NASs or locally attached. And the vendors also differ of the storage array along with the disks.

So I search for a way to measure it with non hardware-tools (like SMART per disk). Far more I would like to know the total amount per LUN/volume or logical storage from VMware directly.

Any hints?

Why?
To have a real life value for deciding what storages to buy. E.g. if a SSD will survive long enough for the needs.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to know this.

Comment: why do you think this?